# Problem on Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I'm really struggling to understand Stokes' Theorem. I tried this exercise:

Let D be the portion of $z=1-x^2-y^2$ above the xy-plane, oriented up, and let $\vec{F}=\langle xy^2,-x^2y,xyz\rangle$. Compute $$\iint_{D}^{}(\nabla\times \vec{F})\cdot \hat{n}dS$$
Here is my work:
$$\nabla\times \vec{F}=\langle xz,-yz,-4xy\rangle$$

$$\vec{f}(r,\theta) = \bigl\langle r\cos\theta ,r\sin\theta ,1-r^2 \bigr\rangle$$

$$\frac{\partial\vec{f} }{\partial r}= \langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-2r\rangle$$

$$\frac{\partial \vec{f}}{\partial\theta }= \langle -r\sin\theta ,r\cos\theta ,0 \rangle$$

$$\frac{\partial\vec{f} }{\partial r}\times \frac{\partial \vec{f}}{\partial \theta}=\left \langle 2r^2\cos\theta ,2r^2\sin\theta ,r\right \rangle$$

$$\left \|\frac{\partial\vec{f} }{\partial r}\times \frac{\partial \vec{f}}{\partial \theta } \right \|=r\sqrt{3}$$
$$\widehat{n}= \biggl\langle \frac{2r\cos\theta}{\sqrt{3}} ,\frac{2r\sin\theta }{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\biggr\rangle$$

Integrating, I have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2r^2\cos^2\theta (1-r^2)-2r^2\sin^2\theta (1-r\cos\theta )-4r\sin\theta\cos\theta\,dr\,d\theta $$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}-2r^2\sin^2\theta (1-r\cos\theta )+2r^2\cos\theta\, \theta (1-r^2)-2r\sin(2\theta )\,dr\,d\theta$$
After splitting the integral into three integrals, I have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}-2r^2\sin^2\theta (1-r\cos\theta )\,dr\,d\theta=-\frac{2\pi }{3\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}2r^2\cos\theta (1-r^2)\,dr\,d\theta =0$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}-2r\sin(2\theta )\,dr\,d\theta =0$$

$$=-\frac{2\pi }{3\sqrt{3}}+0+0$$

But the answer is zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to calculate using double integral instead of using the line integral around its boundary? Also you seem to have some mistakes in your calculations.

Comment: You didn't use Stokes' Theorem!

Comment: @MathLover Yep! The question asked me to use that one in particular, I thought it might be good practice anyway.

Comment: @MatthewPilling What should I have done in this? Is my approach correct?

Comment: You need to identify the boundary of your surface (call this $C$) and then evaluate $\int_CF\cdot dr$ while making sure the normal vector given in the original problem induces the orientation you prescribe to $C$

Comment: Your curl calculation is just wrong, to start with.

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually I wrote the wrong function. Editing.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Do you always have to use the line integral conversion with Stokes' theorem?

Comment: Notice that if the line integral doesn't look so wonderful, you can switch to a different surface whose boundary is the same curve. In this case, you choose the disk in the $xy$-plane, and computing the flux of the curl across that is easy. By symmetry you can immediately see the answer is $0$.  .... Also, you have an error in your derivative of the parametrization. So many places you have to check carefully!

Comment: If you're asked to compute the flux of the curl using Stokes' Theorem then yes you'll want to evaluate the line integral around the boundary.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Not  necessarily. See my previous comment.

Comment: The answer will come to zero but just check your partial derivatives. There are some mistakes there as well.

Comment: @MathLover That's another typo. On my paper I wrote them out correctly. Editing.

Comment: @Ted When the problems says "Use Stokes' Theoem to..." this means calculate the flux of the curl by translating the flux integral into a line integal.

Comment: @CalebWilliamsUIC OK because I get zero using surface integral of the curl too

Comment: @TedShifrin Also, I'm a fan of your book Multivariable Mathematics, I haven't read it nor do I own it obviously but I heard it's great!

Comment: @CalebWilliamsUIC it's a great book! you must get it :)

Comment: @MatthewPilling I taught multivariable calculus for 40 years, and I disagree. If the textbook explicitly says to calculate both sides and verify the theorem, I agree. I certainly taught my students to use the optimal solution that the theorem affords them.

Comment: @MathLover I definitely will when I get the opportunity. You said you got zero using the surface integral of the curl. When I take this surface integral, since the surface D is oriented upwards, do I only have to be concerned with the $\hat{k}$ component of the unit vector $\hat{n}$, since the surface is oriented in that direction? If that's the case, my answer would also come out to zero because I would no longer have to worry about the other integrals that I split up because they just come from multiplication of the $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ components originating from the dot product.

Comment: @Ted Alright alrightttt fine you win ;)

Comment: @CalebWilliamsUIC yes check the $k$ component and then do the dot product. Once you do the dot product, you have just one scalar value to integrate. Also once you find normal vector, you do not need to find _unit_ normal as it will cancel out but if you do, please remember to change $dS$ to $dA$ correctly. In this case, it does not matter as the integral is zero.

Comment: If you get stuck, let us know

Comment: @MathLover This might seem like a slow question to ask, but why don't we need to normalize the vector? Also do I basically set the other components of $\hat{n}$ to zero and then do the dot product?

Comment: Because $dS$ is the surface in 3D and we are parametrizing it and projecting it in $XY$ plane. You did the surface area work of paraboloid couple of days back. Do you remember how we did?  If you normalize it, you also need to then do $dS = ||f_r \times f_{\theta}|| \, dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: @MathLover But if I keep it without being normalized, $dS$ just stays as what?

Comment: then you straight away get to $\iint_D (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \vec{n} \, dr \, d\theta \,$. $\, \vec{n}$ is not normalized.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for clearing that up. I just realized something was indeed wrong with my curl when I converted it to polar. After fixing that, and a few other issues taking the dot product with the normal, and multiplying by the magnitude of the cross product of the vector partials, I have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }\int_{0}^{1}(2r^2cos^2\theta (1-r^2)-2r^2sin^2\theta (1-r^2)-4rsin\theta rcos\theta )r\sqrt{3}drd\theta =0$$

Comment: Yes this is correct!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't apply Stokes' theorem (that is, you insist on computing the integral of the curl over the surface $D$), then you would have

$$\begin{align}
\iint_D(\nabla\times\vec F)\cdot\mathrm d\vec S&=\iint_D\langle xz,-yz,-4xy\rangle\cdot\vec n\,\mathrm dS\\[1ex]
&=\iint_D \langle r(1-r^2)\cos\theta,-r(1-r^2)\sin\theta,-4r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\rangle\cdot\vec n\,\mathrm dS
\end{align}$$

where all I've done here is compute the curl of $\vec F$ and composed it with $\vec f$ to replace $x\to r\cos\theta$, $y\to r\sin\theta$, and $z\to1-r^2$. The normal vector is

$$\vec n=\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial\theta}=\langle2r^2\cos\theta,2r^2\sin\theta,r\rangle$$

So the surface integral reduces to

$$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \left(r^3(\cos(2\theta)-\sin(2\theta))-r^5\cos(2\theta)\right)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$

Note that you do more work than necessary, since

$$\vec n\,\mathrm dS=\left\|\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial\theta}\right\|\frac{\left(\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial\theta}\right)}{\left\|\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial\theta}\right\|}\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=\left(\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\vec f}{\partial\theta}\right)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$

so you don't strictly need to normalize the normal vector.

---

If you do wish to apply Stokes' theorem, the integral is trivial by comparison (I've omitted the details):

$$\int_C \vec F\cdot\mathrm d\vec r=-\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\cos^3\theta\sin\theta-\cos\theta\sin^3\theta\right)\,\mathrm d\theta$$

and both do indeed have the same value.

Comment: I see now. I forgot that $dS$ is literally defined by the magnitude of the cross product of the vector partials times the area element.